# legend labels and colors change to black dc.js d3.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a Composite Chart with two lines built with the following code:

```
function fakeGrouper(source_group) {
                return {
                    all:function () {
                        var cumulate = 100;
                        var result = [];
                        return [{key: 0, value: cumulate}]
                           .concat(source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                              cumulate -= d.value;
                              return {key:d.key, value:cumulate};
                           }));
                    }
                };
            }  

var recDim = cf1.dimension(dc.pluck('recidiefNa'));
                var recGroup = recDim.group().reduceCount();
                var RecGroup = fakeGrouper(recGroup);
                var resDim = cf1.dimension(dc.pluck('residuNa'));
                var resGroup = resDim.group().reduceCount();
                var ResGroup = fakeGrouper(resGroup);


            var scChart = dc.compositeChart("#scStepChart");
            scChart
            .width(600)
            .height(400)              
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,52]))
            .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))
            .clipPadding(10)
            .brushOn(false)
            .xAxisLabel("tijd in weken")
            .yAxisLabel("percentage vrij van residu/recidief")
            .legend(dc.legend().x(70).y(250).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
            .compose([
                dc.lineChart(scChart)
                    .dimension(recDim)
                    .group(RecGroup)
                    .renderDataPoints(true)
                    .interpolate("step-after")
                    ,
                dc.lineChart(scChart)
                    .dimension(resDim)
                    .group(ResGroup)
                    .colors(['#ff9933'])
                    .renderDataPoints(true)
                    .interpolate("step-after")
                ])
            .xAxis().ticks(4);
            scChart.render();
```

Which renders perfectly except for the fact that the legend has 0 as label for both chart. Check out my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8v9faput/

Now i read somewhere that you can solve this by changing the group from:

```
.group(GROUP)
```

to

```
.group(GROUP, LABELNAME)
```

However once i did this the second chart went black in the legend, and the lines are gone in the chart. as shown in this second fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ojdg3ny1/

Any ideas why and how to fix this? I think it might have something to do with me using a fake group.

Comment: im not sure I understand. Where is the 0 as the label ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy if you open the first fiddle you will see that there are 2 0's in the legend as labels

Comment: ah i see, opened the wrong one, ill have a look shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `.colors()` an array. You should pass it single value like so :

```
.colors('#ff9933')
```

So you chart function looks like this :

```
.legend(dc.legend().x(70).y(250).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
                .compose([
                    dc.lineChart(scChart)
                        .dimension(recDim)
                       .group(RecGroup, "Recidief")
                       .colors('red')
                        .renderDataPoints(true)
                        .interpolate("step-after")
                        ,
                    dc.lineChart(scChart)
                        .dimension(resDim)
                        .group(ResGroup, "Residu")
                        .colors('#ff9933')
                        .renderDataPoints(true)
                        .interpolate("step-after")
                    ])
                .xAxis().ticks(10)
                scChart.render();
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/8v9faput/1/